# Hibernation device 'UUID=xxx' not found. None of the solutions working, how do I get the data from the storage then go for a fresh install?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, hibernate, manjaro

As the title says, I started my laptop running Manjaro linux and I get the hibernation device UUID = XXXX not found error. None of the commands are working, not even sudo. None of the solutions I have seen online are working. I am sick of this and not willing to spend any time on this anymore, how do I just get the data from the storage so that I can wipe it with a new installation?

Comment: Use a Live Linux boot media.